# HTTP Status 400 - Required short parameter 'score' is not present, Spring MVC REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am using Spring MVC 4. Here is my controller code:

```
@RestController
public class NewValueController 
{
   @RequestMapping(value="/receiveUpdatedScore",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json"})
   public NewValue receiveUpdateScore(@RequestParam(value="score") short score,
                               @RequestParam(value="user_id") String user_id,
                               @RequestParam(value="device_model") String device_model,
                               @RequestParam(value="api_key") String api_key,
                               @RequestParam(value="gen_t") long gen_t,
                               Model model)
  {
    int newScore = (int) score;
    NewValue algorithm=new NewValue();
    NewValue newvalue=algorithm.getNextValue(newScore);
    return newvalue;
  }
}
```

I am making this Request using Advanced rest client(also tried same in Postman):

```
{"score":"50","user_id":"zyz","device_model":"xiami","api_key":"sasa5454","gen_t":"545666"}
```

*But I am getting following error*

**Error:**

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required Short parameter 'score' is not present

message: Required Short parameter 'score' is not present

description: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

What is the mistake I am not able to detect here. Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Try using  this `@RequestParam("score")` instead

Comment: @Akash Rajbanshi: Yes I tried now. But still the same error. "Required short parameter 'score' is not present" :(

Comment: Change the type of all the parameter to string...

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi But I need them as short and long data types for "score" & "gen_t" to store in a database. I think its not possible to convert from String to short/int/long as they are dissimilar datatypes. Am I right? Any solution?

Comment: Are you sending that JSON in the body?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am sending that json as param values. Also before the return statement ( return newvalue; ) I am going to implement code for storing all the parameter values to database.

Comment: No, I mean the score and others. What is that? How is that sent in the request?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In the Advanced Rest Client, I pass them as parameters.

Comment: Can yoy show us a full dump of the request?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
URL: http://localhost:8080/TestApp/receiveUpdateScore
Request Params: 
{"score":"50","user_id":"zyz","device_model":"xiami","api_key":"sasa5454","gen_t":"545666"}

Comment: I think you are lack of "consumes" parameter in @ RequestMapping annotation and the controller is not aware of the type of data that is coming in the request. Try adding this: consumes={"application/json"}. Second solution will be to retrieve entire object, not the variables one by one. Third possibility will be to retrieve @ Context object and parse variables from given map.

Comment: I changed the ordering of the code like this: i have put 'score' at last and 'user_id' at first.

public NewValue receiveUpdateScore(@RequestParam(value="user_id") String user_id,
                               @RequestParam(value="device_model") String device_model,
                               @RequestParam(value="api_key") String api_key,
                               @RequestParam(value="gen_t") long gen_t,
@RequestParam(value="score") short score,
                               Model model)
Now the error is, 
Required String parameter 'user_id' is not present. What's going wrong? :(

Comment: Yeah, you are very likely not sending query parameters/form parameters, but rather JSON in the body.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you so much bro. Love you. :+1 You are right. In "Post Man" there is option for form parameters. I selected that. It worked. Now my doubt is, android app will be sending this request. So now can the app send as "form parameters" or as  "headers"? I think they will request me by calling RestAPI -> /receiveUpdateScore. If they are sending these params just in the request, what should I change in my controller code? becuase in App, there is no form for user to input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because score is expected as part of the url and not some JSON that you post

Comment: In "Advanced Rest Client", I think we must pass as Json itself all the request parameters. In "Post Man", we have UI for inputing Key-Value pairs. Am I correct?

Comment: To be honest I don't know both programs. What happens if you open the URL in a Browser ?

Comment: Its cumbersome to type so many parameters in URL as, localhost:8080/TestApp/receiveUpdateScore?score=50&user_id=zyz&device_model=xiami&api_key=sasa5454&gen_t‌=545666

Comment: Yes, but if this works you know your code is correct ;-)

Comment: I tried your way. 
http://localhost:8080/TestApp/receiveUpdateScore?score=50&user_id=zyz&device_model=xiami&api_key=sasa5454&gen_t=545666
Now I got error as, Request method 'GET' not supported. But in my code it is, "method=RequestMethod.POST". What is the mistake?

Comment: @Chandz You're sending a GET request through the browser.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can I ask how to send a post request through the browser? I know only -> url?key=value&key=value.... Is there any other type of querying?

Comment: Any request you send through the address bar is a GET. If you want to send a POST, you'll need javascript, or a browser plugin, or through a form, etc.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Okay, I thought everything after url?... will be parameters posting. Now I realized why everyone uses postman or advanced Rest client. Thank you so much.